# Android : Profiling code performance in Nexus 7 using TraceView

Tags: android, profiling, adb, android-traceview

I am trying to profile my code using **traceview** as mentioned in the [android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) . Since nexus 7 tab do not have a external sd card, so I am not able to pull the trace file using a `adb pull <filename>.trace` command.

So my question is **How can profiling be done in devices like nexus 7 which do not support external memory card?**

Answer (score 0):

> Since nexus 7 tab do not have a external sd card, so I am not able to pull the trace file using a adb pull .trace command.

Yes, you can. External storage is not removable storage, and all versions of the Nexus 7 have external storage.